# centering map on array of markers bounds [leaflet]

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to mark a series of markers. I'm using MarkerCluster plugin to create clusters. What I'm doing right now I setting the view of the map to the 1st point of my array. What I wand to do is center the map so the user can see all the points/clusters when the map loads.

My array looks like `m = [L.Marker, L.Marker,...]`. The I add each to my cluster group like:

```
var markers = L.MarkerClusterGroup();
for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
     markers.addLayer(m[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this was very easy I just needed to read some more. All you have to do is `var bounds = markers.getBounds();` and then `map.fitBounds(bounds);` and voila done.