# Zoom to fit all markers in Mapbox or Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

How do I set view to see all markers on map in **Mapbox** or **Leaflet**? Like Google Maps API does with `bounds`?

E.g:

```
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
  latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
}
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Answer (score 361, accepted):

```
var group = new L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3]);

map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

See [the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds) for more info.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it can sometimes cut off a northerly marker, since the marker extends beyonds the bounds given by its coordinates.

Comment: from @user317946: "map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds().pad(0.5)); now the icons wont cut off. :-)"

Comment: I'm glad i Googled this before reinventing the wheel. Thanks

Comment: Just in case it isn't obvious to anyone... You can get bounds of most leaflet objects. map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds()); for example.

Comment: You can use `markers.getBounds().pad(<percentage>)` if you want to extend bounds by a given percentage but you can also pass the padding option to fitBounds in order to set the padding in pixels. `markers.getBounds(), {padding: L.point(20, 20)})`

Comment: This worked for me except I had to remove the word "new"

Comment: how do we do it for multiple groups? I'm using `markerClusterGroup` and there are many clusters and I want to show them all.

Comment: @Robin this works fine for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207357/5723816

Comment: I only recently found out that instead of L.layerGroup I should use L.featureGroup - that still keeps the remaining syntax the same, but also enables me to use .getBounds()

Comment: how to do this with mapbox only, no leaflet?

Answer (score 31):

The 'Answer' didn't work for me some reasons. So here is what I ended up doing:

```
////var group = new L.featureGroup(markerArray);//getting 'getBounds() not a function error.
////map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(markerArray);
map.fitBounds(bounds);//works!
```

Comment: Trying to do this but getting Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]. Any idea?

Comment: tried it got: `Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid.`

Comment: I am sorry folks. I have not used this technology in years; as you can see, the Question was posted by me years ago. @fayssalelansari : I suggest print the Bounds in browser's console to see if the values look okay. Best luck you all.

Answer (score 21):

```
var markerArray = [];
markerArray.push(L.marker([51.505, -0.09]));
...
var group = L.featureGroup(markerArray).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Comment: It works without the addTo(map): map.fitBounds(L.featureGroup(markerArray ).getBounds()); will this make any difference?

Answer (score 17):

Leaflet also has LatLngBounds that even has an extend function, just like google maps.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds

So you could simply use:

```
var latlngbounds = new L.latLngBounds();
```

The rest is *exactly* the same.

Comment: Thank you! For me the solution, per the Answer above, was returning 'getBounds() is not a function. So I changed my code per your suggestion. I have it in my own Answer.

Answer (score 12):

Belatedly, I didn't see any answers using Mapbox, despite Mapbox has more functionality such as padding, animation, and max zoom.

```
const coordinates = [<coordiantes>...]

// Create a 'LngLatBounds' with the first coordinate.
const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(
  coordinates[0],
  coordinates[0]
);
 
// Extend the 'LngLatBounds' to include every coordinate in the bounds result.
for (const coord of coordinates) {
  bounds.extend(coord);
}

// Note there are other options such as easeing animation and maxZoom
map.fitBounds(bounds, {
  padding: 20
});
```

[Demo](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/)

Answer (score 7):

For Leaflet, I'm using

```
    map.setView(markersLayer.getBounds().getCenter());
```

Comment: This was the only solution I could get to work with a single marker in Chrome

Answer (score 7):

You have an array of L.Marker:

```
let markers = [marker1, marker2, marker3]

let latlngs = markers.map(marker => marker.getLatLng())

let latlngBounds = L.latLngBounds(latlngs)

map.fitBounds(latlngBounds)
// OR with a smooth animation
// map.flyToBounds(latlngBounds)
```

Answer (score 4):

You also can locate all features inside a FeatureGroup or all the featureGroups,
see how it works!

```js
//Group1
m1=L.marker([7.11, -70.11]);
m2=L.marker([7.33, -70.33]);
m3=L.marker([7.55, -70.55]);
fg1=L.featureGroup([m1,m2,m3]);

//Group2
m4=L.marker([3.11, -75.11]);
m5=L.marker([3.33, -75.33]);
m6=L.marker([3.55, -75.55]);
fg2=L.featureGroup([m4,m5,m6]);

//BaseMap
baseLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [3, -70],
  zoom: 4,
  layers: [baseLayer, fg1, fg2]
});

//locate group 1
function LocateOne() {
    LocateAllFeatures(map, fg1);
}

function LocateAll() {
    LocateAllFeatures(map, [fg1,fg2]);
}

//Locate the features
function LocateAllFeatures(iobMap, iobFeatureGroup) {
  if(Array.isArray(iobFeatureGroup)){   
   var obBounds = L.latLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < iobFeatureGroup.length; i++) {
    obBounds.extend(iobFeatureGroup[i].getBounds());
   }
   iobMap.fitBounds(obBounds);   
  } else {
   iobMap.fitBounds(iobFeatureGroup.getBounds());
  }
}
```

```css
.mymap{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map" class="mymap"></div>
<button onclick="LocateOne()">locate group 1</button>
<button onclick="LocateAll()">locate All</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

To fit to the visible markers only, I've this method.

```
fitMapBounds() {
    // Get all visible Markers
    const visibleMarkers = [];
    this.map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            visibleMarkers.push(layer);
        }
    });

    // Ensure there's at least one visible Marker
    if (visibleMarkers.length > 0) {

        // Create bounds from first Marker then extend it with the rest
        const markersBounds = L.latLngBounds([visibleMarkers[0].getLatLng()]);
        visibleMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
            markersBounds.extend(marker.getLatLng());
        });

        // Fit the map with the visible markers bounds
        this.map.flyToBounds(markersBounds, {
            padding: L.point(36, 36), animate: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a point Layer (in this case a GeoJSON source)
let pointLayer = L.geoJSON(pointSource, {
    pointToLayerL pointToLayer,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
//Add the newly created layer to the mapObject
pointLayer.addTo(mapObject);

//Set a padding variable for the space around the bounds
let paddingCoef = (0.5);

//Call the fit bounds to adjust to the padded extent of points.
mapObject.fitBounds(pointLayer.getBounds().pad(paddingCoef));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the next code

```
var group = new L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3]);

map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Comment: there is similar answer

Answer (score 0):

in MapBox you can use fitBound method.

you can use [docs.mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/)