# getBounds() of defined group of markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm wanting to zoom a mapBox map to a specific group of markers based on a shared property.

I have a map with a bunch of markers, and from that group I've built two arrays for two separate regions like so:

```
var regionOne = [], regionTwo = [];

map.markerLayer.on('layeradd', function(e){

  var marker = e.layer,
      feature = marker.feature;

   switch (feature.properties.region) {
      case 'region-one':
        regionOne.push(feature);
        break;
      case 'region-two':
        regionTwo.push(feature);
        break;
    }
});
```

but I am stuck on next steps. I need to convert the array of marker objects to a featureGroup (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845614/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-in-mapbox-or-leaflet) and documented [in the leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup)) so I can apply the `getBounds()` method but just running

```
var regionGroup = new L.featureGroup(regionOne);
```

throws an error, even though `regionOne` is a valid array of mabox marker objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `regionOne` and `regionTwo` arrays are populated?

It doesn't appear that the `feature` object is accessible in your function. Give this a shot:

```
map.markerLayer.on('layeradd', function(e){
   var layer = e.layer;
   switch (layer.properties.region) {
      case 'region-one':
        regionOne.push(layer);
        break;
      case 'region-two':
        regionTwo.push(layer);
        break;
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Need to assign the `layer` to each array, not the `feature`.

```
var regionOne = [], regionTwo = [];

map.markerLayer.on('layeradd', function(e){

  var marker = e.layer,
      feature = marker.feature;

   switch (feature.properties.region) {
      case 'region-one':
        regionOne.push(marker);
        break;
      case 'region-two':
        regionTwo.push(marker);
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I had defined `feature` earlier in the code but not included it in the snippet. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Give the edited answer above a shot. The name can be confusing, but the `featureGroup` expects an array of `ILayers` just like the `layerGroup`.