# Determine the center point of multiple polygons in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

How can I determine a point central to multiple polygons?

What I mean is a point that is indicated as a red dot in the attached figure.
PS: The number of polygons can vary. The algorithm should be able to determine an approximate point which is central to a majority of the polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches to this, depending on what you exactly want.

The easiest one is to calculate the centroid of the polygons as a whole. A lot of geospatial software is capable of calculating centroids of multipolygons, polygons with multiple outer rings, etc.

If you're using Leaflet and GeoJSON, my personal choice would be to use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) for the geoprocessing, e.g.:

```
var poly1 = {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [[[10, 10], [10, 20], [20, 15]]]
  }
}; 

var poly2 = {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [[[10, 45], [20, 40], [20, 50]]]
  }
};

var featCollection = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [poly1, poly2]
}

L.geoJSON(featCollection).addTo(map)

// Magic happens here:
var centroid = turf.centroid(featCollection);

L.geoJSON(centroid).addTo(map);
```

You can see that as a [working example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/vom/edit?html,output).

Now, the centroid is the center of *density* of the polygons. If you remember high-school geometry, you remember there are [lots of centers for something as simple as a triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center), each with its own properties.

This is true for more complex polygons: [some times you don't want the centroid](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/polygon-center/). If you take geodesics into account (i.e. the fact that the earth is not a 2D plane), things get... way more complicated.

So depending on what you want to do, you might want a more elaborated solution, in order to find not the centroid, but a point which minimizes the distance to any of the polygons (understood as the minimum distance to any of the vertices to that polygon).

Comment: How can I automatically adjust the zoom level of the map to fit all/ a majority of the polygons?

Comment: Get the bounds for every polygon, and create an instance of `L.Bounds` that extends over all the bounds. Read the leaflet docs, it should be simple to do by yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845614/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-in-mapbox-or-leaflet  ---> helped me