# Show All Cluster Markers in react-leaflet-markerclusterer using React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

My React Typescript app is displaying a Leaflet map with marker clusters using `react-leaflet` &  `react-leaflet-markerclusterer`.

However, I am unable to get the map to show all cluster markers inside the map view. I am attempting to [convert this JS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61667303/741099) to Typescript.

One of the errors shown in the. JS console is

> React Hook "useMap" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

In VSCode, there is also a Typescript error

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

on the line

```
const groupBounds = group.getBounds();
```

Why is this happening, and what is the proper way to write this Typescript code?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';

interface IProps {
    markers: {
        lat: number;
        lon: number;
    }[];
    
    mapCenter: {
        lat: number;
        lon: number;
    };
}

export function MapView({markers, mapCenter}: IProps): JSX.Element {

    const groupRef = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (groupRef !== undefined) {
            const group = groupRef.current;
            const map = useMap();                   // ERROR: React Hook "useMap" cannot be called inside a callback.
            const groupBounds = group.getBounds();  // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
            map.fitBounds(groupBounds);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <MapContainer
            center={[mapCenter.lat, mapCenter.lon]}
            zoom={10}
            style={{ width:'100%', height:'100vh' }}
            className='markercluster-map'
        >
            <TileLayer 
                url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${access_token}`}
            />
            <MarkerClusterGroup ref={groupRef}>
                {
                    markers.map((marker, index) => (
                        <Marker 
                            position={[marker.lat, marker.lon]} 
                            key={index}
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </MarkerClusterGroup>
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a typescript issue, this is a react issue.  Hooks [need to be called either within the top level of the function body, or as part of another custom hook](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).  The same applies to react-leaflet's `useMap`.  You can move it outside the `useEffect`. However a `useMap` hook call must be part of a component that is a child of the `MapContainer` so that it has access to the leaflet context object.  You can abstract this logic into its own component, like in [this example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap), but I think you're better of using a `whenCreated` with a state variable to grab an instance of the `L.Map` and use it in the effect:

```js
export function MapView({markers, mapCenter}: IProps): JSX.Element {

    const groupRef = useRef();
    const [map, setMap] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (groupRef && map) {
            const group = groupRef.current;
            const groupBounds = group?.getBounds();
            map.fitBounds(groupBounds);
        }
    }, [map, groupRef]);

    return (
        <MapContainer
          whenCreated={map => setMap(map)}
          moreProps={moreProps}
        >
           <Stuff />
        </MapContainer>
    )

}
```

If TS is still complaining that `group` or `map` is undefined, you can use the optional property operator `?.` on them:

```js
if (groupRef && map) {
  const group = groupRef?.current;
  const groupBounds = group?.getBounds();
  map?.fitBounds(groupBounds);
}
```

Typescript should be smart enough to know that `groupRef` and `map` are defined, as they're in the `if` statement, but it may still complain about `group` being defined.  You could also do `if (groupRef && groupRef.current && map)` to remove all doubt.

**Note: Make sure you are using the correct [version of react-leaflet-markercluster](https://github.com/YUzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster#getting-started) that is compatible with react-leaflet v3.

Comment: Thanks, the using `whenCreated` worked awesome for me.